# Counting the number of results for a pandas.loc search

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns "user" (userid) and "TS" (timestamp).

```
>>> print rawData
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 74883 entries, 0 to 74882
Data columns (total 2 columns):
TS      74883  non-null values
user    74883  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
```

I've ensured that the dataframe is indexed on the 'user' field.

```
>>> indexedDataFrame = rawData.set_index('user')
```

So that now I can get the list of timestamps for a user.

```
>>> indexedDataFrame.loc['user1','TS']
user
user1   1423217959.064690
user1   1423217959.204906
user1   1423217959.324809
...
user1   1423220404.366348
user1   1423221013.064749
Name: TS, Length: 3151, dtype: float64
```

This allows me to find the number of entries for this user by counting the
number of entries in the array.

```
>>> indexedDataFrame.loc['user1', 'TS'].count()
3151
```

So far so good. The problem occurs when there is only a single entry for a
user. In that case, pandas, presumably to make it easier for users, returns the
entry directly instead of an array with one value. Unfortunately, this means that the count operation
fails since you can't call count() on a float.

```
>>> indexedDataFrame.loc['user15', 'TS']
1423217968.5711029

>>> indexedDataFrame.loc['user15', 'TS'].count()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-259-8712c5fa66de> in <module>()
----> 1 indexedDataFrame.loc['user15', 'TS'].count()

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'count'
```

So this means that if I want to write a function that counts the number of
timestamps for each user, I have to do the following:

```
def findEventCounts():
    userCountMap = {}
    for user in distinctUsers:
        print "Counting entries for user %s" % user
        searchResult = indexedDataFrame.loc[user, 'TS']
        try:
            userCount = searchResult.count()
        except AttributeError:
            userCount = 1
        print user, userCount
        userCountMap[user] = userCount
    return userCountMap
```

which is stupid and ugly.

Unfortunately, this behavior of returning the value instead of an array with a
single entry actually shows up in the pandas documentation as well, so I'm
pretty sure that this is expected behavior.

(See the last example in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label,

```
# this is also equivalent to ``df1.at['a','A']``
In [44]: df1.loc['a','A']
Out[44]: -1.7769037169718671
```

)

Is there a workaround, or do I really have to write ugly code like the above to
use pandas? If it is the latter, I'm not going to use pandas... :)

Comment: Aside: you might want to read up on `groupby`-- your `findEventCounts` can be written in one line.

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the nudge! I did check out groupby earlier, but calling `count()` on the result (e.g. `rawData.groupby('user').count()` just returned the number of groups.

Your prompting lead me to the `.size()` (e.g. `rawData.groupby('user').size()` method, which works, and as you say, is a single line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a one-element list as the index to force it to return a Series even if there is only one match:

```
indexedDataFrame.loc[['user1'], 'TS']
```

(You can also use a multi-element list to get multiple indices at once, e.g., `indexedDataFrame.loc[['user1', 'user2'], 'TS']` to get all rows for both users.)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Is this documented somewhere, or is it a secret convention that pandas gurus know? I looked through the pandas documentation on indexing and didn't find this there...

Comment: @Shankari: Unfortunately the pandas documentation is not that great at providing a comprehensive statement of what kinds of indexing do what.  It is [documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix) that you can index with a list, but examples are only given for multi-element lists, and it's not specifically stated that this forces a Series result for a one-element list.